# what should printf("%.17g\n", .1) print?

Tags: c, bash, printf, posix, stdio

I've often used the command-line program "printf"
to test/predict what the C stdio library function will do.

But I've recently found that doesn't work (any more?)--
at least on a recent linux/ubuntu release,
the command-line printf (both the bash builtin and /usr/bin/printf)
sometimes gives different results from the C function.

That means if I want to see what the C function will do,
I have to run some other program that actually calls the C function, such as (apparently)
python, perl, gnuplot, or an actual C program.

Here's a demonstration, on linux:

```
bash$ uname -srvmpio
    Linux 3.13.0-95-generic #142-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 12 17:00:09 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
bash$ bash --version
    GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
    Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
bash$ type printf
    printf is a shell builtin
bash$ printf "%.17g\n" .1
    0.1
bash$ /usr/bin/printf "%.17g\n" .1
    0.1
bash$ python -c 'print "%.17g" % .1'
    0.10000000000000001
bash$ perl -e 'printf("%.17g\n", .1);'
    0.10000000000000001
bash$ gnuplot -e 'print sprintf("%.17g", .1)'
    0.10000000000000001
bash$ echo -e '#include <stdio.h>\nint main(){printf("%.17g\\n",.1);}' | gcc -xc - -o /tmp/printf_.1 && /tmp/printf_.1
    0.10000000000000001
```

On some other platforms, e.g. an up-to-date macbook, they all give "0.10000000000000001"
(which I've always thought was the right answer):

```
bash$ uname -srvmp
    Darwin 15.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 15.6.0: Thu Jun 23 18:25:34 PDT 2016; root:xnu-3248.60.10~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64 i386
bash$ bash --version
    GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin15)
bash$ type printf
    printf is a shell builtin
bash$ printf "%.17g\n" .1
    0.10000000000000001
bash$ /usr/bin/printf "%.17g\n" .1
    0.10000000000000001
```

I'm of course surprised and disappointed that the above commands don't all give exactly the same output within any particular platform.
My question is: is there a single correct answer, according to some official spec, and, in any case, should a bug report be filed?

Some background facts:

.1 in C denotes the IEEE double-precision floating-point number
whose value is exactly, mathematically:

```
x  = 0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625
```

and the adjacent representable values are:

```
x- = 0.09999999999999999167332731531132594682276248931884765625
x+ = 0.10000000000000001942890293094023945741355419158935546875
```

Therefore both string representations "0.10000000000000001" and "0.1" are non-lossy,
in the sense that they are both closer to x than to any other double-precision value;
that is, any reasonable string-to-double conversion function will produce
x when given either string.  So both answers are equally good in this sense.

However, 0.10000000000000001 is closer to x than 0.1 is.
I've always thought that implies "0.10000000000000001" is the right answer,
but now I'm not sure; maybe it's an implementation-dependent detail?

For an explanation of why 17 is the right number of digits to be using in any case, see
the documentation for numeric_limits::max_digits10:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/max_digits10

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n2005.pdf

Comment: @user3386109 "help printf" says bash printf does what /usr/bin/printf does, plus a couple of enhancements.  "man printf" says /usr/bin/printf does what C printf does.   So if C printf has a correct answer, that answers all of them definitively... if not, I have to make a more subtle argument that it would be really helpful if they would all give the same answer (within a given platform at least).

Comment: You shouldn't try to compare single precision values (float), they are not exact

Comment: @user3386109 you removed the tag "stdio" and added "bash"; I disagree with that.  In my view, this question isn't really about bash; bash behavior defers to /usr/bin/printf which is the program I expect to be more well-behaved and speced.   stdio is a more relevant tag than bash.

Comment: My understanding of the question is that you think the `bash` built-in should match the C `printf`. However, the behavior of the `bash` built-in changed between versions 3.2 and 4.3. So obviously you should ask the `bash` experts why that change occurred.

Comment: @user3386109 all right I see your point-- it would be interesting to know why bash changed, as well as why /usr/bin/printf changed.   I'm going to remove "linux" and add back "stdio".

Comment: Ok, although I'm not sure that you'll reach any experts with the `stdio` tag that you didn't already reach with the `C` tag.

Answer (score 4):

Following is about C in general and may/may not apply to `bash` or `posix` specifications.

`printf("  %.17f\n", .1)` is *expected* to print at least  `DBL_DECIMAL_DIG` correct *significant digits*. `DBL_DECIMAL_DIG` is the precision guaranteed for a `double` to decimal textual representation back to `double` and get the same result.  To do this, at least 10 and commonly 17 significant digits are correct.  This is OP's situation which OP certainly understands well.

```
//0.09999999999999999167332731531132594682276248931884765625
//0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625
//0.10000000000000001942890293094023945741355419158935546875
//  12345678901234567
  0.10000000000000001  // DBL_DECIMAL_DIG is commonly 17
```

The problem is, `printf()` is not *required* to do any of this very correctly.  So the quality of `printf()` would be considered marginally acceptable if it printed either of the two below as `0.1` could round-trip via either text successfully.

```
//  12345678901234567
  0.10000000000000001 
  0.10000000000000000
```

> The accuracy of the floating-point operations (+, -, *, /) and of the library functions in `<math.h>` and `<complex.h>` that return floating-point results is **implementation defined**, as is the **accuracy of the conversion between floating-point internal representations and string representations** performed by the library functions in `<stdio.h>`, `<stdlib.h>`, and `<wchar.h>`. The implementation may state that the accuracy is unknown.  C11dr §5.2.4.2.2 6

---

[Edit]

A `double` can have various precision, base, range details.  For simplification, this discussion is about a sample value than it not 0.1, but 0.10000000000000000555...

The comment of [@user694733](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39652130/what-should-printf-17g-n-1-print/39654936?noredirect=1#comment66612876_39654936) is useful, yet it is under "Recommended practice" which uses "*should* be a exact ...".  Although it does not specify the hoped for "0.10000000000000001" for `printf("%.17f", .1)`.  It, along with the above helps answers OP's question: "What *should* print?",  "0.10000000000000001" *should* be printed.  But that accuracy is implementation defined by C.

For a C implementation that claims compliance to [EEE floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point), I am confident that a result of "0.10000000000000001" *or* "0.10000000000000000" is required, but that is beyond a C question and into a IEEE 754-xxxx one.  My reading of [IEEE floating point Character representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point#Character_representation) allows a conforming implementation that latitude as only round-tripping a `double` (actually [binary64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)) --> text --> `double` is required.  This takes at least 15 significant digits and may take as many as 17.  What those digits are past the 15th is not specified other than the conversion of the text to `double` returns the starting `double`.

---

Deeper.  For IEEE 754, a value of `0.100000000000000005551115123...` could "wrongly" print as anything up to "0.10000000000000001249000902..." and still correctly round-trip.

```
//  12345678901234567
//0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625
//0.10000000000000001249000902...  half way
//0.10000000000000001942890293094023945741355419158935546875
```

Note: IEEE allows converting text to a `double` to *ignore* significant digits beyond a certain amount (20 for `double`).

---

Short IEEE answer: output should lie within the range of `[C I]` below when printing `X` to various precisions.

```
    12345678901234567
A 0.099999999999999991673327315... preceding X
B 0.099999999999999998612221219... half way
C 0.099999999999999998613          half way rounded to 20 sig digits toward x
D 0.099999999999999999             "%.17e" candidate
E 0.10000000000000000              "%.17e", "%.17f" candidate 
X 0.100000000000000005551115123... 
G 0.10000000000000001              "%.17e", "%.17f" candidate
H 0.10000000000000001249           half way rounded to 20 sig digits toward x 
I 0.100000000000000012490009027... half way
J 0.100000000000000019428902930... following X
```

Comment: Also, about the nearest value in 7.21.6.1 p13: *"... If the number of
significant decimal digits is more than DECIMAL_DIG but the source value is exactly
representable with DECIMAL_DIG digits, then the result should be an exact
representation with trailing zeros. **Otherwise, the source value is bounded by two
adjacent decimal strings L < U, both having DECIMAL_DIG significant digits; the value
of the resultant decimal string D should satisfy L ≤ D ≤ U**, with the extra stipulation that
the error should have a correct sign for the current rounding direction."*